# How do I handle a ValueError?

Tags: python

I'm using `index()` on a string to find the occurrence of a substring.

When the substring does not exist within the string, I get:

```
"ValueError: substring not found".
```

I want my program to be able to recognize when this is happening, but I don't know how to turn the `ValueError` into something useful. For example, how can I use getting a `ValueError` in an `if` statement?

Answer (score 7):

Generally you could use try and except for catching exceptions but in this case as mentioned by John you could just use find().

```
try:
   #your code that raises the exception
except ValueError:
   #turn it into something useful
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't wait for the exception.  Use `find()` instead of `index()` and you will avoid having exceptions at all.  Just test for not-found and be done with it.